# BOTO3 Waiter Types for SSM

Tags: python, boto3, documentation, aws-ssm

Does anyone know the available waiter types for SSM? The BOTO3 documentation is missing a section. It says ["See the waiters section"](http://botocore.waiter.Waiter), but there is no such a section.

Googling online didn't help much, as it's not a common topic at all.

Comment: If there are no waiters listed in the docs, then it doesn't have any. Most services don't.

Comment: @jordanm OK. I thought the documentation just missed out on that section. Anyway, I don't think there are any waiters for this SSM service despite there is a "get_waiter()" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify this as follows:

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

print(ssm.waiter_names)
```

This will print out empty array:

```
[]
```

For comparison, for **ec2**:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

print(ec2.waiter_names)
```

Will give (not all shown):

```
['export_task_completed',
 'image_available',
 'image_exists',
 'instance_exists',
 'instance_running',
 'instance_status_ok',
 'instance_stopped',
 'subnet_available',
 'system_status_ok',
 'volume_available',
 'volume_deleted',
 'volume_in_use',
 'vpc_available',
 'vpc_exists',
 'vpc_peering_connection_deleted',
 'vpc_peering_connection_exists',
 'vpn_connection_available',
 'vpn_connection_deleted']
```

`get_waiter` method is probably inherited from some parent class.

Comment: Thank you! I was chasing goose after all on the SSM doc page :(

Comment: FYI, as of boto3 1.14.47, SSM now has one type of waiter:

```
print(ssm.waiter_names)  >>>>> ['command_executed']
```

Comment: @gye Thanks for letting me know. This is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there's only a `command_executed` waiter.

From the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Waiter.CommandExecuted):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ssm')
waiter = client.get_waiter('command_executed')
waiter.wait(
    CommandId='string',
    InstanceId='string',
    PluginName='string',
    WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 123,
        'MaxAttempts': 123
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a homegrown waiter you can try:

```
def send_command_wait_for_succes(commandid, instanceid):
    '''wait for success status, or end after 2 minutes'''
    cnt = 0
    while True:
        response = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
            CommandId=commandid,
            InstanceId=instanceid)
        if response['Status'] != 'Success':
             time.sleep(5)
             cnt = cnt + 1
             if cnt == 24:
                return False
                break
        else:
            return True
            break

print(send_command_wait_for_succes(commandid, instanceid))
```